# Rearrange NSMutableArray depending on Order from 2nd Array

Tags: ios, ipad, nsmutablearray

I have `NSMutableArray` stored dictionary which need to be sorted out.... sorting depend on Fields present in another array....

Example:

> Array 1 ==> Red - 1, White - 2, Green - 3. Array 2 ==> Green, Red,
>   White
>
> Result should be Array 3 => Green - 3, Red - 1, White - 2. (items in
>   Array 1 is sorted depend on Order in Array 2).

Comment: Why don't you build it in a double `for` ? For each element in array 2, you find the corresponding one in array 1 and add it to array 3.

Comment: yeah .... i did that but some how i m feeling its not best way... there might be very good way.... much simple then having two for loops....if apple provides anything....even though apple stuff i tried to find out but did not found any...

Comment: Also, you could replace Array 1 with a single dictionary and then you'll have instant access to each element's value.

Comment: no but if element in both arrays differs then.... both are flexible arrays...

Answer (score 0):

In case your first array looks like: `[{@"Red": @1}, {@"White": 2}, {@"Green": 3}]`, the next approach should work:

```
NSArray* array3 = [array1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary* dict1, NSDictionary* dict2) {
        NSUInteger idx1 = [array2 indexOfObject:[dict1 allKeys][0]];
        NSUInteger idx2 = [array2 indexOfObject:[dict2 allKeys][0]];

        if(idx1 < idx2) return NSOrderedAscending;
        if(idx2 > idx1) return NSOrderedDescending;
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
```